# Cant find class DiffCallback in Android Architecture component 1.1.1:

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

Recently I updated android.arch support library version in gradle file

```
 // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"

    // alternatively, just ViewModel
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"

    // alternatively, just LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    // Room (use 1.1.0-alpha1 for latest alpha)
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"

    // Paging
    implementation "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha7"
```

Now I stated getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [`DiffUtil.ItemCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil.ItemCallback.html) class:

```
 public static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User> DIFF_CALLBACK =
             new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<User>() {
     @Override
     public boolean areItemsTheSame(
             @NonNull User oldUser, @NonNull User newUser) {
             //..
     }
     @Override
     public boolean areContentsTheSame(
             @NonNull User oldUser, @NonNull User newUser) {
         //..
     }
 }
```

You can also check the  [`DiffCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/DiffCallback.html) class. Now this class is moved in `recyclerview-v7` and it is **deprecated**.

Comment: I'm not getting latest `DiffUtil` class although I updated RecyclerView by adding `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'`. Any idea what is the issue?@GabrieleMariotti

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which version you were using earlier, but from the [changelog ( 1.0.0-alpha6, February 27, 2018)](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/release-notes.html),

> Classes renamed, and moved to recyclerview-v7:
>
> - DiffCallback -> DiffUtil.ItemCallback